# Check the date is greater than 0001-01-01 in Moment.js

Tags: json, momentjs, date-comparison

I have a function which formats date using,

```
export function FormatDate(date: string) {
if (date != null) {
    return moment.utc(date).format('DD MMM YYYY');
}
else
    return "";
}
```

But the issue is that null dates are received as "0001-01-01" (DateTime Min value). how can I check it with moment js?

Could not find a straight forward way to do it. Following code works, but it's ugly,

```
new moment("0001-01-01").format("DD MMM YYYY") == moment.utc(date).format("DD MMM YYYY")
```

The "date" I receive is in "/Date(-62135596800000)/" format.

I tried, `moment.utc(date).isAfter("0001-01-01")` and it's not working as well, returns true.

What is the best way to check serialized date is not the minimum date?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are missing the timezone part when comparing the dates. Please see the below code and let me know if this is what is required:

```
var minDate = moment.utc("0001-01-01"); // minimum value as per UTC

var receiveDate = moment("/Date(-62135596800000)/"); // replace with variable
if(moment.utc(receiveDate).isAfter(minDate)){
     alert('yebo !');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in c# format You can do this

```
    var dateObject = "/Date(-62135596800000)/";
    var ScriptDate = new Date(parseInt(dateObject.substr(6)));
    var minDate = moment.utc("0001-01-01");
    if(moment.utc(ScriptDate).isAfter(minDate)){ 
        console.log("Correct date"); 
    }else{ 
        console.log("Incorrect date"); 
    }
```